# Encountering stack overflow while implementing recursive Bubble sort

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion, stack-overflow, bubble-sort

Hey I converted [this C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644440/bubble-sort-using-recursion-in-c-sharp#1644596) to c++ as

```
void bubbleSort(int *inputArray, int passStartIndex, int currentIndex,int length)
{
    if(passStartIndex == length - 1) return;
    if(currentIndex == length - 1) return bubbleSort(inputArray, passStartIndex+1, passStartIndex+1,length);

    //compare items at current index and current index + 1 and swap if required
    int nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    if(inputArray[currentIndex]>inputArray[nextIndex])
    {
        int temp = inputArray[nextIndex];
        inputArray[nextIndex] = inputArray[currentIndex];
        inputArray[currentIndex] = temp;
    }

    return bubbleSort(inputArray, passStartIndex, currentIndex + 1,length);
}
```

but when I execute it on input array of having length 50100, it shows me expcetion

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in example.exe

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: I saw the bug that @Benoit found, too, but I still can't see why the recursion does not terminate. The test of `passStartIndex` seems pretty solid. BTW, I ran this code on my Linux box and got a segmentation fault, not a stack overflow, though that might mean the same thing. However, the failure happened for me when length was 510, not 50100. I am thinking that the stack is getting clobbered somehow, not infinite recursion. Unfortunately, I don't have any more time for this. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ***"What am I doing wrong?"***

Each time recursive function calls itself, the call frame (*activation record*) is stored into the stack memory. So when the recursion gets too deep, which is the moment when you reach the maximum size of stack, the execution is terminated.

Also have a look at: [Does C++ limit recursion depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630054/does-c-limit-recursion-depth)

---

#### ***"How to fix it?"***

The easiest way how to avoid this problem is to never design your algorithm as a recursion at first place. But once you already have a recursive solution like this, in most cases it's possible to rewrite it into the loop form or (which is usually much easier): a **tail recursion**.

Basically if you can rewrite your function in a way that it never directly passes any arguments to the next call, you won. If you look at your recursion, there are 2 spots, where it calls itself and before the call is made, only `currentIndex` and `passStartIndex` are being changed. Imagine that you would store these indexes somewhere aside and the current function call would just signal *"I'm done, these are values that someone should continue with: ... Now you may continue!"*, which means that state, the function is at, is not needed to be stored. By doing so you'll end up with a  ***[Tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)*** (see especially [first example program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Example_programs)).

Here's the full example of how it could be done with your code: *[Step 1](http://ideone.com/Vu8nGy)*, *[Step 2](http://ideone.com/7YLI5u)*

Answer (score 3):

It will not solve your problem (see recursion limit), but there is a mistake in the algorithm that you used. You should replace

```
if (currentIndex == length - 1)
    return bubbleSort(inputArray, passStartIndex+1, passStartIndex+1, length);
```

by

```
if (currentIndex == length - 1)
    return bubbleSort(inputArray, passStartIndex+1, 0,length - 1);
```

The bubble sort should restart to 0, because the first item is not at the right place, but the last one is.